# Google Cloud Builder - Build trigger fails with "Requested resource was not found"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup a build trigger for a Cloud Source Repositories project. This repo simply includes:

- cloudbuild.yaml
- Dockerfile
- readme.md

I configured a build trigger to run when specific tags are pushed and specified "cloudbuild.yaml" as the ocation for my build configuration file. This config file contains:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/k8s-kubectl:$TAG_NAME', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/k8s-kubectl:latest', '--build-arg', 'VCS_REF=$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/k8s-kubectl:$TAG_NAME'
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/k8s-kubectl:latest'
```